# Facebook API - get profile feed with authors' avatars

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to fetch data from user's wall and it goes well - just simple request to Facebook Graph API:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=...
```

However it returns:

```
"data": [
      {
         "id": "1337_123",
         "from": {
            "name": "Johny Rambo",
            "id": "1337"
         },
         "message": "hello world",
         ...
       },
       ...
]
```

What I also need is author's avatar (picture) - in that case `Johny Rambo`.

I can ask Facebook API for it with other request like:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/1337?access_token=...&format=json&fields=name,picture
```

But it makes a `n+1` requests to the API (`n` - number of wall posts if authors are unique).

Is it possible to modify main request for wall posts to fetch `from` section with users' pictures like below ?

```
         "from": {
            "name": "Johny Rambo",
            "id": "1337",
            "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/......jpg"
         },
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can simply use the ID as the image with `/picture`:

`<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/1337/picture"/>`

> You can render the current profile
>   photo for any object by adding the
>   suffix /picture to the object URL.

For more information, have a look at the [documentation here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) under "pictures".

Comment: This URL redirects to the place where the picture actually is. This won't work if you use this URL in a component that doesn't handle 302 redirects, like an Android image view.